# how to get latest record or record with max corresponding date of all distinct values in a column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

For Example, I have table like this:

```
Date      | Id | Total
-----------------------
2014-01-08  1    15
2014-01-09  3    24
2014-02-04  3    24
2014-03-15  1    15
2015-01-03  1    20
2015-02-24  2    10
2015-03-02  2    16
2015-03-03  5    28
2015-03-09  5    28
```

I want the output to be:

```
Date      | Id | Total
---------------------
2015-01-03  1    20
2014-02-04  3    24
2015-03-02  2    16
2015-03-09  5    28
```

Here the distinct values are Id. I need latest Total for each Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `left join` as

```
select 
t1.* from table_name t1
left join table_name t2
on t1.Id = t2.Id and t1.Date >t2.Date
where t2.Id is null
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Max() in sql:

```
SELECT date, id, total
   FROM table as a WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date)
   FROM table as b
  WHERE a.id = b.id
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable D
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM YourTable WHERE ID = D.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is by using `INNER JOIN`

Find the `latest` date per `ID` then join result back to the table to get the `value`

```
select A.ID,A.Date,A.value 
from yourtable A 
INNER JOIN 
(
select MAX(date) as Date,ID 
from yourtable
group by ID 
) B
ON A.ID =B.ID and A.Date = B.Date
```

Answer (score -2):

The other answers didn't work for me. I found the following code, which worked great  for me:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE IN (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM TABLE)
```

I am using SSMS 2014, SQLServer