# How to display only the MAX results from a query

Tags: sql-server, max

I am new to writing MS SQL queries and I am trying to display only the record with the highest field named RecordVersion. 
Below is the query that works but displays all records:

```
SELECT        
    PriceCalendars.PriceProgramID, 
    PriceCalendars.EffectiveDateTime, 
    PriceSchedules.Price, 
    PriceSchedules.PLU, 
    items.Descr, 
    PriceSchedules.LastUpdate, 
    PriceSchedules.LastUpdatedBy, 
    PriceSchedules.RecordVersion, 
    PriceSchedules.PriceScheduleUniqueID
FROM            
    PriceCalendars 
    INNER JOIN PriceSchedules ON PriceCalendars.PriceProgramID = PriceSchedules.PriceProgramID 
    INNER JOIN items ON PriceSchedules.PLU = items.PLU
WHERE        
    (PriceSchedules.PLU = 'SLS10100103') 
    AND (PriceCalendars.EffectiveDateTime = '2016-03-22')
```

Here are the query results:

```
PriceProgramID  EffectiveDateTime   Price   PLU Descr   LastUpdate  LastUpdatedBy   RecordVersion   PriceScheduleUniqueID

1   2016-03-22 00:00:00.000 35.00   SLS10100103             Architecture Adult from NP POS  2015-01-22 07:53:15.000 GX70,83     9   569

1   2016-03-22 00:00:00.000 32.00   SLS10100103             Architecture Adult from NP POS  2014-02-25 16:22:46.000 GX70,83     5   86180
```

The first line of the results has RecordVersion being 9 and the second line results is 5, I only want the higher record displaying, the one that returned RecordVersion = 9.

Every time I try to use the MAX command I get errors or the group by and I have tried every example I could find on the web but nothing seems to work.

Using MS SQL 2012.
Thanks,
Ken

Comment: looks like duplicate. I have seen many of this case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984670/how-to-get-latest-record-or-record-with-max-corresponding-date-of-all-distinct-v

Comment: What makes the two the same so that you just want one of them? The PriceProgramID, the PLU Descr, the PriceScheduleUniqueID (or any combination of them all)?

Comment: Have you tried using `SELECT TOP 1` and `ORDER BY RecordVersion DESC` ?  This might be sufficient for your use-case, but I am not sure.

Comment: simple rule,all columns in group by should be in select except aggregates

Comment: The reason for the query is the newest record has the correct price for a ticket (PLU) on a selected day. The future prices are changed often due to weather and we need to use this query to display today's price for XX ticket on our video displays. Thank you all for the help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following query which attempts to solve your problem by ordering the returned rows by `RecordVersion DESC` and then SELECTs just the first row.

```
SELECT TOP 1      
    PriceCalendars.PriceProgramID, 
    PriceCalendars.EffectiveDateTime, 
    PriceSchedules.Price, 
    PriceSchedules.PLU, 
    items.Descr, 
    PriceSchedules.LastUpdate, 
    PriceSchedules.LastUpdatedBy, 
    PriceSchedules.RecordVersion, 
    PriceSchedules.PriceScheduleUniqueID
FROM            
    PriceCalendars 
    INNER JOIN PriceSchedules ON PriceCalendars.PriceProgramID = PriceSchedules.PriceProgramID 
    INNER JOIN items ON PriceSchedules.PLU = items.PLU
WHERE        
    (PriceSchedules.PLU = 'SLS10100103') 
    AND (PriceCalendars.EffectiveDateTime = '2016-03-22')
ORDER BY
    RecordVersion DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

All group by columns should be in select ,that's the rule of group by.How group by works is for every distinct combination of group by columns,arrange remaining columns into groups,so that any aggregation can be applied,in your case I am not sure what group by columns are unique with out test date.here is one version which use row number which gives you the output desired

Remember ,order by last updated date is the one which decides rows order and assign numbers

```
WITH CTE
AS
(    
   SELECT  PriceCalendars.PriceProgramID, 
    PriceCalendars.EffectiveDateTime, 
    PriceSchedules.Price, 
    PriceSchedules.PLU, 
    items.Descr, 
    PriceSchedules.LastUpdate, 
    PriceSchedules.LastUpdatedBy, 
    PriceSchedules.RecordVersion, 
    PriceSchedules.PriceScheduleUniqueID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PriceSchedules.RecordVersion ORDER BY PriceSchedules.LastUpdatedBy) AS RN
FROM            
    PriceCalendars 
    INNER JOIN PriceSchedules ON PriceCalendars.PriceProgramID = PriceSchedules.PriceProgramID 
    INNER JOIN items ON PriceSchedules.PLU = items.PLU
WHERE        
    (PriceSchedules.PLU = 'SLS10100103') 
    AND (PriceCalendars.EffectiveDateTime = '2016-03-22')
    )
    SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: Not certain, but I think the `PARTITION BY` in your query 'wants' to use the column `PriceProgramID` rather than `RecordVersion`.

Comment: May be ,I am not sure,i thought record version was unique,best way to get more answers is provide some test data and expected output along with query tried so far

Comment: Thank you but this query still displays two rows of data and we need a response from the query of just one line. Thank you still for the help.